# limitipconn_module is not working in apache httpd

Tags: apache

I have been trying to limit no of connection per ip , so i have configured "limitipconn_module" by using following steps.

1.wget http://dominia.org/djao/limit/mod_limitipconn-0.24.tar.bz2

2.extracting mod_limitipconn-0.24.tar.bz2 and cd mod_limitipconn-0.24

3 ./usr/local/apache/bin/apxs -i -a -c mod_limitipconn.c
   this will create entry in httpd.conf file

4 after that i wrote in httpd.conf file

```
  <IfModule mod_limitipconn.c> 
    <Location /somewhere>
    MaxConnPerIP 3
    </Location>
   </IfModule>
```

its not working

5 i also tried to  create separate file in /usr/local/apache/conf/mod_limitipconn.conf and write above lines and include file in httpd.conf

still not working

whats wrong with this configuration please help.